# Export Fluent Nhibernate Schema and Alter Table

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am able to generate and export the schema creation script from Fluent Nhibernate.
Sometime I would like to just modify some fields or add new ones to a table after the schema creation without deleting all the tables.
What I do now is that I generate the first schema script and then manually add or modify the fields to the db during the development process.

- It is possible to generate with Fluent Nhibernate Schema Export statements with ALTER TABLE instead CREATE TABLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure is possible

```
new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(true, true);
```

Comment: Where can you set the option to save the exported sql to file?  SchemaExport has a SetOutputFile method, but SchemaUpdate doesn't appear to.

Comment: The actual schema is outputted to the console and if you want it to look a bit nicer I recommend using nhibernate profiler ( http://nhprof.com/download ) when updating the schema it logs the whole darn thing nicely. It also logs any errors detected during schema update.

Comment: The first parameter of Execute is for generating the script though I don't know how to actually save it to anywhere. The second parameter is for executing the update.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Action and Pass it to the SchemaUpdate method

```
string script = "LogFile.txt"
if (!File.Exists(script))
    File.Create(script);

// writes out an alter table script
Action<string> updateLogFile= x =>
{
    //Open up file, append
    using (var file = new FileStream(script, FileMode.Append))
    {
        //Write each line
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
            sw.Write(x);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
};

// Perform Schema update into updateLogFile Action
new SchemaUpdate(config)
    .Execute(updateLogFile, true);
```